# Initializing "a pointer to an array of integers"

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, initialization

```
 int (*a)[5];
```

How can we Initialize a pointer to an array of 5 integers shown above.

Is the below expression correct ?

```
int (*a)[3]={11,2,3,5,6};
```

Comment: There's never any good use for "pointer to array" in C. It just obscures the code for no benefit. Just declare and initialize the array, and use pointers to its element type.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: That's not true - a pointer to array is the most efficient way to dynamically allocate a multidimensional array (as in `int (*a)[5] = malloc(nrows * sizeof *a);`)

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty simple, but that only applies when you know the inner dimension at compile time, not in the more general case.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: works just as well for VLAs: `size_t cols; ...; int (*a)[cols] = malloc( nrows * sizeof *a );`.  It's also what a 2D array expression decays to when passed to a function.  The OP's usage is incorrect, but that doesn't make them useless.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Suppose you have an array of int of length `5` e.g.

```
int x[5];
```

Then you can do `a = &x;`

```
 int x[5] = {1};
 int (*a)[5] = &x;
```

To access elements of array you: `(*a)[i]` (== `(*(&x))[i]`== `(*&x)[i]` == `x[i]`) parenthesis needed because precedence of `[]` operator is higher then `*`. (one common mistake can be doing `*a[i]` to access elements of array).

Understand what you asked in question is an compilation time error:

```
int (*a)[3] = {11, 2, 3, 5, 6};
```

It is not correct and a type mismatch too, because `{11,2,3,5,6}` can be assigned to `int a[5];` and you are assigning to `int (*a)[3]`.

Additionally,

You can do something like for one dimensional:

```
int *why = (int p[2]) {1,2};
```

Similarly, for two dimensional try this(thanks @[caf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134633/caf)):

```
int (*a)[5] = (int p[][5]){ { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } , { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } };
```

Comment: @Flow second not correct try ,as  `int (*a)[5]= (int(*)[5])&({11,2,3,5,6});` with new compiler

Comment: `int (*a)[5] = (int [][5]){ { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } , { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 } };`

Comment: @caf got it Thanks its similar to: `int *why = (int[2]) {1,2}`

Comment: @caf got it!! my commented expression is not correct because I am using `&` before constant

Comment: @caf your expression is `c99` **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Yes.  It's a compound literal.

Comment: @caf Thanks! I was trying find it in my experiment and that time you given me an answer Thanks Caf :)

Comment: Very interesting. I have never needed before such syntax. But, I believe, there is a small mistake in the beginning: `(*a)[i] == (&x)[i]` is not correct -- it is `(*a)[i] == (*(&x))[i]`.

Comment: @kavadias  Yes you are correct,  thanks for correcting my answer!!  if you are not  aware of  this you may find  it interesting - [The GNU C Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Declaring-Pointers)

Comment: Again, you added `(*&x)[0]` by mistake, instead of `(*&x)[i]`, I believe. What needs to be clarified is that `a == &x`. It follows that he elements of the array would be indexed the same as if you had defined `int **a = &x`. Don't you agree?

Comment: @kavadias thanks for correcting and upvote :) ... regarding `int **a = &x`, if `x` is declared as `int x[5]` then type of `x` is `int (*)[5]` and `int**` is not compatible with `int (*) [5]`. Yes this code `int x[5]; int * a = x;` is valid code in which array name `x` decays into address of first element that is of type `int*`.

Comment: I did not say it is the same declaration or type for `a`. The elements of `x[]` are accessed through `a` _as if_ `a` was of type `int **`. In other words, `a` is a pointer to `x`, i.e., a pointer to a pointer of specific type and dimension --nevertheless, `a` **is** a pointer to a pointer (of the type of `x`).

Answer (score 5):

`{11,2,3,5,6}` is an *initializer list*, it is not an array, so you can't point at it. An array pointer needs to point at an array, that has a valid memory location. If the array is a named variable or just a chunk of allocated memory doesn't matter.

It all boils down to the type of array you need. There are various ways to declare arrays in C, depending on purpose:

```
// plain array, fixed size, can be allocated in any scope
int array[5] = {11,2,3,5,6};
int (*a)[5] = &array;

// compound literal, fixed size, can be allocated in any scope
int (*b)[5] = &(int[5]){11,2,3,5,6};

// dynamically allocated array, variable size possible
int (*c)[n] = malloc( sizeof(int[n]) );

// variable-length array, variable size
int n = 5;
int vla[n];
memcpy( vla, something, sizeof(int[n]) ); // always initialized in run-time
int (*d)[n] = &vla;
```

Comment: @M.M Indeed. Not sure why I wrote that. Fixed. I suppose I was trying to warn about passing a pointer to a compound literal outside the scope where it was declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
int a1[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int (*a)[5] = &a1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int vals[] = {1, 2};
int (*arr)[sizeof(vals)/sizeof(vals[0])] = &vals;
```

and then you access the content of the array as in:

```
(*arr)[0] = ...
```