# Do C arrays declared without malloc() need to be checked for validity?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

(I'll reword the title if anyone has a suggestion, I know it's somewhat awkward.)

When allocating memory for dynamic arrays in C using `malloc()`, I know to check if the call was successful by verifying that the pointer is not NULL. Does that same check need to be performed for explicitly declared arrays in C, such as in the following example (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850998/initializing-a-pointer-to-an-array-of-integers))?

```
char arrinit[5];
char (*arrinit_two)[5] = &arrinit;
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean exactly the posted code?

Comment: @iharob Is there a problem with that code?

Comment: yes it's invalid, see my answer.

Comment: @haccks the code is declaring `arrinit` twice...

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to give the second variable a different name, just fixed that.

Comment: @iharob; Didn't notice that.

Comment: When memory allocated on stack then there is no need to manage the memory yourself, variables are allocated and freed automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: No!

The compiler will assure, that your arrays will have enough memory that you define statically.

Normally (depending, how you declare them), they will be allocated on the stack and when you don't have enough memory on the stack left, your program is likely to crash before you can make any checks or you will not be able to do any remedies.

BTW: You also will not get an NULL value, anyhow, since the system will give you some address value, even when no memory is left (or it has crashed before).

**There is of course one case, where you should be careful:** When you want to allocate really big amounts of memory (a big array), than you should do it with malloc. On many systems, the stack size is limited for processes, so that it is more likely that your system crashes, when you allocate big amounts of memory on stack (the compiler does it for you) than when you do it with malloc (because there are not the same limits).

But of course on today's computers, this means, that you can have arrays of at least some MB before it has any effect. For arrays < 1MB, you don't need to bother.

Comment: There is no such thing as the **system stack**.

Answer (score 3):

If you define an array object, checking whether it was allocated successfully is either unnecessary or impossible.

If it's defined with *static storage duration* (i.e., either defined outside any function body or defined with the `static` keyword), then the amount of memory needed is determined at compile time, and allocated when your program is loaded. If there's not enough room, depending on the system, chances are your program will just fail to execute.

If it's defined inside a function with no `static` keyword, then the memory is allocated when the function is called or on entry to the block containing it. If *that* allocation failed, the behavior is undefined. Most commonly the program will die with a "stack overflow" or something similar. The language doesn't provide a way to detect in advance whether such an allocation will succeed, or to detect after the fact that it failed.

Which means that something like this:

```
{
    char arr[5];
    if (arr != NULL) ...
}
```

will almost certainly never detect any allocation failure; the address of a declared object is always non-null.

Answer (score 2):

No, if the pointer points to a stack variable no check is required, and I guess you mean

```
int  array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *pointer;

pointer = array;
if (pointer != NULL) /* will always be true */
...
```

there are compiler warnings that would warn about

```
if (array != NULL)
```

and tell you that this condition is always true.

In the case you declare a pointer and point to it, like

```
int *pointer = array;
```

then the compiler will not be able to warn you, but still the condition cannot be false because the array is allocated when the function stack frame is created, so if it's not possible to allocate the array, then it will be impossible to call the function.